# Check if match is from right or left side of the stringB and return the difference

Tags: javascript

We have this code:

```js
const stringA = "enjoying your new car";
const stringB = "are you enjoying your new car";

var regexp = new RegExp(stringA + "$", "ig");
const notIncluded = stringB.replace(regexp, '');

console.log(notIncluded);
```

Here is the rule:

`stringA` always is a part of `stringB` and it matches some portion of `stringB` from **right** or **left**.

For instance in the above code we have `stringA` which is matching a part of `stringB` **from the right** of `stringB` . right?

The second rule is we want to fill `notIncluded` with a portion of `stringB` which is not included in `stringA`... As our code suggests... ok?

Now I need a function to give us the same `notIncluded` just as the above code (stringB  - stringA) somehow!!!

But I want another functionality here:

I want an if else statement to check if the matching is from right side of the `stringB`  (like what we have in the above) or from left side.

So if we have these:

```
const stringA = "enjoying your new car";
const stringB = "are you enjoying your new car";
```

the `notIncluded` would be :

```
"are you"
```

and the check (if statement or the variable) shows the match is from **right**.

In opposite if we have these:

```
const stringA = "enjoying your new car";
const stringB = "enjoying your new car are you";
```

the `notIncluded` would be the same again:

```
"are you"
```

This time the check (if statement or the variable) shows the match is from **left** side of the `stringB`.

Comment: Seems like this could be solved more straight forward without regex

Comment: `stringB.remplace(stringA, '')` is not enough?

Comment: No I want to check matching from one direction not from everywhere...

Comment: Check this to understand why it doesn't work:

Comment: `const stringA = "enjoying your new car";
const stringB = "are you enjoying your new car separation here enjoying your new car";
console.log(stringB.replace(stringA, ''));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use [`string.startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and [`string.endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith).

```js
const stringA = "enjoying your new car";
const stringB = "are you enjoying your new car";
let fromLeft = false, fromRight = false;
let notIncluded = "";

if (stringB.startsWith(stringA)) {
  fromLeft = true;
  notIncluded  = stringB.substr(stringA.length);
} else if (stringB.endsWith(stringA)) {
  fromRight = true;
  notIncluded = stringB.substr(0, stringB.length - stringA.length)
}

console.log(fromLeft, fromRight, notIncluded);
```